# Summation Of Series of $\binom{x+k}{k+1}$ where $k$ is $0$ to $n$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Want The formula or to find The Sum of Series where

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{x+k}{k+1}$$

where $x$ is any constant $\geq 1$  and $n$ is another constant.

Answer (score 3):

By Pascal's identity,

$$\binom{x+k}{k+1} = \binom{x+k+1}{k+1} - \binom{x+k}{k}.$$

So by telescoping,

$$S = \binom{x+n+1}{n+1} - \binom{x}{0} = \binom{x+n+1}{n+1}- 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{x+k}{k+1}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{x+k}{x-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \left[\binom{x+k+1}{x}-\binom{x+k}x\right]\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \binom{x+k}x-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{x+k}x\\
&=\binom{x+n+1}x-1\qquad\blacksquare \\
\end{align}$$